# Touchscreen assignment with multiple x-screens

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr, touchscreen, xinput

I am having troubles assigning the touch input to a specific monitor when the desktop is divided into multiple x-screens, as xinput does not seem to have an option to specify the correct x-screen.

```
> xrandr -q --screen 0
Screen 0:
*****
DP-1 connected
DP-2 disconnected

> xrandr -q --screen 1
Screen 1:
*****
DP-3 connected
DP-4 ....
```

Now, I would like to assign the touch controller (xinput id 10) to DP-1, but xinput does only know what is on screen 1:

```
> xinput map-to-output 10 DP-1
Unable to find output 'DP-1'. Output may not be connected.
```

How do I tell xinput to look on screen 0 for that specific output??

Comment: we have actually a very similar issue: 1 X-Server, 4 X-Screens The X-Screens have each an associated touch input (AccuTouch 2218). We cannot assign a touch to a specific screen. We tried the "evdev" driver as this works fine with 1 X-Server, 1 X-Screen setup (and of course four monitors). The trick with xinput map-to-output <input-device-id> <physical-port-on-card> worked fine in case we have one (tiled) X-screen. @user794763: Are there any news on your issue? - Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 xinput map-to-output 10 DP-1
```

You can also export the DISPLAY variable

EDIT : This doesn't work on my usecase .. sorry for loss of time :/